# linux kernel proper way to unlink a file

Tags: c, linux, kernel

Linux 3.2.2 kernel

I examined the source code in fs/namei.c and found do_unlinkat which performs the entire operation but takes a user space pointer. I was wondering if there is a function that does this except in the kernel space (i do have the struct path to the file, inode, and dentry)
I could just copy the code from the function into my own. But I was just wondering how it works as well?

Answer (score 0):

Did you understand the [`fs/namei.c:do_unlinkat()`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/bwh/linux-3.2.y.git;a=blob;f=fs/namei.c;hb=HEAD) function at all? It does exactly what you want, except that it uses

```
     error = user_path_parent(dfd, pathname, &nd, &name);
     if (error)
         return error;
```

to look up the `struct nameidata`. If successful, the kernel-side copy of `pathname` will be stored in `name` (which has to be freed using `putname(name)`).

However, the same file contains the implementation for the `user_path_parent()` function, too. It is very simple, so you should have no trouble understanding what it does. Indeed, aside from copying the userspace-`pathname` to kernel-side `name`, it really just does a `do_path_lookup()` call, which operates solely on kernel-side structures.

Using the above, you can make minor modifications to `do_unlinkat()` to implement your own kernel-side `unlinkat()` function. If this is code you hope will someday be accepted upstream, you should also refactor the two functions so that there is no repeated code. Perhaps something along the lines of

```
/*
 * Make sure that the actual truncation of the file will occur outside its
 * directory's i_mutex.  Truncate can take a long time if there is a lot of
 * writeout happening, and we don't want to prevent access to the directory
 * while waiting on the I/O.
 */
static long kern_unlinkat(int dfd, const char *name)
{
    long error;
    struct dentry *dentry;
    struct nameidata nd;
    struct inode *inode = NULL;

    error = do_path_lookup(dfd, name, LOOKUP_PARENT, &nd);
    if (error)
        return error;

    error = -EISDIR;
    if (nd.last_type != LAST_NORM)
        goto exit1;

    nd.flags &= ~LOOKUP_PARENT;
    error = mnt_want_write(nd.path.mnt);
    if (error)
        goto exit1;

    mutex_lock_nested(&nd.path.dentry->d_inode->i_mutex, I_MUTEX_PARENT);
    dentry = lookup_hash(&nd);
    error = PTR_ERR(dentry);
    if (!IS_ERR(dentry)) {
        /* Why not before? Because we want correct error value */
        if (nd.last.name[nd.last.len])
            goto slashes;
        inode = dentry->d_inode;
        if (!inode)
            goto slashes;
        ihold(inode);
        error = security_path_unlink(&nd.path, dentry);
        if (error)
            goto exit2;
        error = vfs_unlink(nd.path.dentry->d_inode, dentry);
exit2:
        dput(dentry);
    }
    mutex_unlock(&nd.path.dentry->d_inode->i_mutex);
    if (inode)
        iput(inode);    /* truncate the inode here */
    mnt_drop_write(nd.path.mnt);
exit1:
    path_put(&nd.path);
    return error;

slashes:
    error = !dentry->d_inode ? -ENOENT :
        S_ISDIR(dentry->d_inode->i_mode) ? -EISDIR : -ENOTDIR;
    goto exit2;
}

static long do_unlinkat(int dfd, const char __user *pathname)
{
    long error;
    char *name = getname(pathname);

    if (IS_ERR(name))
        return PTR_ERR(name);

    error = kern_unlinkat(dfd, name);

    putname(name);

    return error;
}

EXPORT_SYMBOL(kern_unlink);
```

If the above works -- I didn't bother to test it; all that is up to you --, then you can use `kern_unlinkat(directoryfd, pathname)` or `kern_unlinkat(AT_FDCWD, pathname)` in your own kernel module to remove a file by specifying its pathname in a kernel-side string `pathname`.

If you already have the nameidata, then you can obviously change the above to match what code is common and what is not. But, considering the trickyness of the details (dentry locking in particular), I'd just use the pathname if I were you.

Happy hacking, and good luck.